# math algorithm c#

Tags: c#

I have a c# application that calculates a sequence of numbers as follows:

```
    int nth = 0; 
for(int i = numbers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   if(i % x == 0) {
     nth = i;
     break;
    }
}
return nth;
```

what I'm not clear about is how do I show/Get the nth instance of the sequence where (n divide x) has no remainder and display that output in label2

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [mcve] (preferably in a console app) with sample inputs and expected sample outputs.

Comment: Could you give samples of such a "nth instance where (n divide x) has no remainder"? What is `n` (both) and `x` here?

Comment: @HansKesting i want to take the above result(numbers.add(result)) and only show the numbers that doesnt have a remainder in label2

Comment: What is your expected output (e.g. do you want `1,3,105` or something else)?

Comment: @mjwills yes thats what i want 1,3,9,105... and so on.so each time the button is clicked and the numbers are shown,it must  check if there is no remainder and display that number in label2

Answer (score 1):

You can try a `for` loop like

```
int nth = 0; 
for(int i = numbers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   if(i % x == 0) {
     nth = i;
     break;
    }
}
return nth;
```